# How to check if 2 images with different file names are identical with PHP

Tags: php, image

I am getting images from the WEB and sending them to an S3 bucket on AWS. Each image gets a random name. But I don't want to store identical twins. So, before storing the image on my server (to then sending it to S3), I need to check if an identical image already exists there (on S3).

I cannot do the check on my server, because files will be deleted after successfully sent to S3.

Here is my code:

```
$filenameIn  = $url_img;
$nome = randomString();
$nome_img = "$nome.png";
$filenameOut = __DIR__ . '/img/' . $nome_img;
$contentOrFalseOnFailure = file_get_contents($filenameIn);
$bucket = 'bucket-img';

if( !$contentOrFalseOnFailure ) {
return "error1: ...";
}

$byteCountOrFalseOnFailure = file_put_contents($filenameOut, $contentOrFalseOnFailure);

if( !$byteCountOrFalseOnFailure ) {
return "error2: ...";
}

// Instantiate the S3 client with your AWS credentials
$aws = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
  'version' => 'latest',
  'region'  => 'sa-east-1',
  'credentials' => array(
      'key'    => 'omissis',
      'secret' => 'omissis',
  )
 ]);

 /*
  I BELIEVE AT THIS POINT I SHOULD MAKE A COMPARISON TO CHECK IF THE FILE THAT 
  IS ABOUT TO BE SENT TO S3 HAS AN IDENTICAL TWIN THERE, REGARDLESS OF THEIR 
  RANDOM NAME. IF SO, UPLOAD SHOULD BE ABORTED AND THE SCRIPT SHOULD PROVIDE 
  ME WITH THE URL OF THE TWIN. 
 */
 try{
 // Send a PutObject request and get the result object.
$result = $aws->putObject([
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'        => $nome_img,
    'SourceFile' => $filenameOut,
    'ACL' => 'public-read'
]);

$r = $aws->getObjectUrl($bucket, $nome_img);
return $r;
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
  return $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

As I said in the code, I should get the url of the twin file, if it exists.

Is that possible?

Comment: It depends how you define *"identical"*. Are two 64x64 red squares identical if one is a BMP and the other a GIF? Are two PNGs identical if they both contain a blue 32x64 rectangle but one was created a second after the other and therefore has a different timestamp within the metadata? Depending on the answer, you could create a hash (md5 checksum or better of the entire image) and store the hash for all your images and check before committing. Or you could checksum just the pixels and not the metadata....

Comment: Well, identical means the same image. That is because I would be scraping images from the same website. So I guess if I compare the image `sha1_file()` value with the same value from the image that is already on my S3 bucket I would accomplish my goal...is that right?

Comment: Yes. I was hinting you keep a copy of the hash sum locally as you commit each image to S3 and then you don't need to drag all files back locally and re-calculate to compare each time you add a new one.

Comment: hum...well thought. Thanks.